Type inference for generic type using a switch statement in type script
I am trying to create a generic type that has different configurations. These configurations are the only difference between the implementations.
The below snippit should illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:
interface Generic<Config extends ConfigurationType> {
    configuration_type: Config
    configuration: TypeToConfigMap[Config]
}

class ConfigA { z = 1 } // empty classes make bad examples
class ConfigB { y = 2 }
class ConfigC { x = 3 }

const enum ConfigurationType {
    a = 'a',
    b = 'b',
    c = 'c',
}

interface TypeToConfigMap {
    [ConfigurationType.a]: ConfigA,
    [ConfigurationType.b]: ConfigB,
    [ConfigurationType.c]: ConfigC,
}

The main part of interest would be the following example function
function test(generic: Generic<ConfigurationType>[]) {
    generic.forEach((generic) => {
        switch (generic.configuration_type) {
            case (ConfigurationType.a):
                generic.configuration.z;
                break;
            case (ConfigurationType.b):
                generic.configuration.y;
                break;
            case (ConfigurationType.c):
                generic.configuration.x;
                break;
        }
    })
}

However the type of the generic nor the config within the switch cases are not inferred. I would like to implement it this way as it would leave the code clean unlike many other approaches. Is there a way to implement the above code in such a way that the type of generic and the member configuration can be inferred?

did you mean switch (generic.configuration_type) instead of switch(ConfigurationType)?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] that demonstrates what you're talking about when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs. Any pseudocode, or typos, or syntax errors, make it a lot harder for us to help you. Right now there are a bunch of problems in there unrelated to your question.

(see prev comment) Take a look at this playground link. Do you agree that the Problem section accurately demonstrates your problem? If so then please [edit] to use that code (or let me know and I'll do it). Then, do you agree that the Fix section fixes the problem? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz yes your what you wrote in the playground exactly captures my problem and the fix is indeed solves my problem. My apologies for not writing accurate code, I wasn't quite sure how accurate it had to be. I'll edit my code to reflect the problem section in your playground example.

The problem is that your definition of Generic<Config> doesn't automatically distribute over unions in Config. So while Generic<ConfigurationType.a> is what you expect, Generic<ConfigurationType> is not:
type G = Generic<ConfigurationType>;
/* type G = {
  configuration_type: ConfigurationType;
  configuration: ConfigA | ConfigB | ConfigC;
} */

You can see that there is no correlation between the configuration_type property and the configuration property.  The former could be ConfigurationType.a while the latter is ConfigB.

What you want is for Generic<X | Y | Z> to distribute over that union and be equivalent to Generic<X> | Generic<Y> | Generic<Z>. First, let's rename your Generic out of the way:
interface _Generic<Config extends ConfigurationType> {
    configuration_type: Config
    configuration: TypeToConfigMap[Config]
}

Now we want to define Generic<Config> as a distributive version of _Generic<Config>. There are a few ways to get that to happen. One is to make Generic a distributive conditional type:
type Generic<Config extends ConfigurationType> =
    Config extends unknown ? _Generic<Config> : never

That might look like a no-op, because every type in TypeScript extends the unknown top type. But when a conditional type checks a generic type parameter like Config, then the resulting type distributes over unions in that type parameter. So in some sense this is a no-op, except that it distributes over unions.  Now if we check it, we see the expected type:
type G = Generic<ConfigurationType>;
/* type G = 
   _Generic<ConfigurationType.a> | 
   _Generic<ConfigurationType.b> | 
   _Generic<ConfigurationType.c> */

Another way to write this is to make Generic<Config> a distributive object type as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109:
type Generic<Config extends ConfigurationType> =
    { [C in Config]: _Generic<C> }[Config]

This is a mapped type over the elements of Config, into which we immediately index with Config. This results in the same union:
type G = Generic<ConfigurationType>;
/* type G = 
   _Generic<ConfigurationType.a> | 
   _Generic<ConfigurationType.b> | 
   _Generic<ConfigurationType.c> */

Either way will serve your purpose:
function test(generic: Generic<ConfigurationType>[]) {
    generic.forEach((generic) => {
        switch (generic.configuration_type) {
            case (ConfigurationType.a):
                generic.configuration.z; // okay
                break;
            case (ConfigurationType.b):
                generic.configuration.y; // okay
                break;
            case (ConfigurationType.c):
                generic.configuration.x; // okay
                break;
        }
    })
}

I usually prefer distributive object types where possible (you can only use them when the unions you distribute over are keylike; that is, if they are assignable to string | number | symbol), because TypeScript "understands" them for generics better than it "understands" generic conditional types. But in your example you're not keeping Config generic (your function deals only with the specific type Generic<ConfigurationType>) so they will behave identically in this example.
Playground link to code
